# How can I check if user logged in via mobile or using an application?

Tags: 8

On the login page, can we check if users logged in via mobile or using an application?

Basing on that, I need to check things.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that, the [Browscap](https://www.drupal.org/project/browscap) module.

> Browscap provides an improved version of PHP's get_browser() function.
>   The get_browser() function can be used to tell what a visitor's browser is capable of. Unfortunately, the version provided by PHP has a number of limitations, namely:
>   It can be difficult or impossible to configure for shared hosting environments.
>   The data used to identify browsers and determine their capabilities requires consistent maintenance to keep up-to-date.
>   Browscap automates maintenance by storing browser data in a database and automatically retrieving the latest data on a configurable schedule.

Configurating it is very easy, and you can use it with the Panels module to display or not a block if the user logged-in via mobile or not.

The current Drupal 8 version is 8.x-3.0-alpha2.

[image]